# How to append all the elements to the list?

Tags: python, list, append

I am currently trying to make a list of events in a webscraping program but somehow it prints all the events, but when i print the list, it only prints the last event even though it's written at the same level of indentation.

This is the code:

```
dictionar = { 'casa':'',
              'nume':'',
              '1'   :'',
              'x'   :'',
              '2'   :''}

evenimente = []

url_fortuna = "https://efortuna.ro/"
response_fortuna = requests.get(url_fortuna)
soup_fortuna = BeautifulSoup(response_fortuna.text, "html.parser")

container_fortuna = soup_fortuna.find_all('tr')

for element in container_fortuna:
    dictionar['casa'] = 'fortuna'
    events = element.find_all('span',class_="market-name")
    odds = element.find_all('span',class_="odds-value")[0:3]
    if odds != []:
        for event in events:
            dictionar['nume'] = event.text
        dictionar['1'] = odds[0].text
        dictionar['x'] = odds[1].text
        dictionar['2'] = odds[2].text
        print(dictionar)
        evenimente.append(dictionar)
print(evenimente)
```

So when the 'dictionar' is printed, everithying is okay,
but when i print 'evenimente', only the last event is printed few times and i don't understand why.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You only have one `dictionar` that you keep modifying(overwriting previous values).  Put `dictionar = {}` at the start of the loop to create a new dictionary for each list entry.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can check if odds are exist

```html
if odds:
```

and you do not need to take fist 3 indexs with [0:3] you can check with writing like this [:3]

Comment: I tried to run code in my pc but the site is closed so I could not try could be about the list of fortuna or you can specialize container_fortuna = soup_fortuna.find_all('tr') with class

Comment: I tried to run your code in my pc but the site is closed. The problem is could about the list of fortuna you can specialze it

Comment: thanks for the optimization, the problem was as @samwise wrote above

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).